# Why doesn't QGIS georeferencer support gdal scripting for projective transformation?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, gdalwarp

I am georeferencing drone images with QGIS, and the transformation method that gives the best results is the projective one.

As I have many images, I would like to write a gdal script to automate the process.

However, when I hit the "generate GDAL script" button, I get the following error:

> GDAL scripting is not supported for projective transformation.

Is it gdalwarp which doesn't support projective transformation, or is QGIS georeferencer that doesn't implement it?

Comment: Gdalwarp https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html supports only tps (-tps) and polynomial (-order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it.

Based on the source code:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/georeferencer/qgsgeoreftransform.cpp

GDAL is only used for the three polynomial transformations and the thin plate spline.

Comment: Thank you for helping... and to remind me that sometimes "the code is the doc" !

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, so i checked the world file only (linear transforms) in the transformation settings window and it worked.